How do I change the color of the edges of an ActiveX Command Button in Excel (i.e., the Highlight and Shadow)?
I'm still fairly new to using Macros and Controls in Excel, but I have a tendency to quickly start mucking about with advanced functions and features that are way beyond my skill level, which I fear is what I'm doing.
I've read mixed reviews on ActiveX controls, but I'm trying them out -- in particular, the Command Button, as the title states.  I've figured out how to change the button background color (BackColor) and the text color (ForeColor), but I'm struggling to figure out how to change the edge highlight and shadow.  They just stay gray.
Just as an example, I made this button with a green background and pink text using the Properties palette, and I made the cell background light blue, just for contrast.  But the edges of the button are still shades of gray.
awful green button with gray edges
I've tried researching to see if there are more color properties (e.g., "ButtonEdgeShadow" or "ButtonEdgeHighlight") that can only be manipulated in VBA, but everything I read only seems to mention BackColor and ForeColor properties in their VBA code (which I already found in the Properties palette, and don't affect the edge color).
I noticed that when selecting colors for BackColor and ForeColor in the Properties palette, I can choose System Colors (including colors called "Button Shadow" and "Button Highlight"), and the edges of the Command Buttons seem to match these System Colors, which makes me think that the edges of the Command Buttons are governed by these System Colors.
From what I understand, the System Colors in Excel are actually just the colors in the Windows Registry... and changing the Windows Registry for this just doesn't seem like a good solution, especially if I want to have buttons that are multiple colors, or if a file containing buttons is used by other people from their own computers.  I tried checking to see if it's possible to somehow to "unlink" the Excel System Colors from the Windows Registry and assign custom values to them within Excel... but that seems illogical, even with my limited understanding of how this all works.
I know that I could just use Shapes and assign macros to them, and that would give more control over their appearance, but they don't visually behave like a button (i.e., when clicked, the text doesn't shift down to the right, and the edge highlights and shadows don't change).  I've also found some sites offering more advanced Buttons (for a price).  I could also just get over it and let the edges be gray.  But I just want to know if this specific problem with ActiveX Command Buttons has a solution.
'Preciate your time.

VBA and ActiveX in general is an aging technology. Sure it's great to have, but it's still lacking a bit, and I don't think that Excel's ActiveX form controls offers this level of customization and foreground/background is likely all you're going to get. "Advanced buttons" you refer to are probably a shape or image made to look like a button, or maybe even COM library with custom form controls that were created outside of VBA. If it means that much you might be able to get away with using an image of a button and placing that into your forms.

"(i.e., when clicked, the text doesn't shift down to the right, and the edge highlights and shadows don't change)" but this too can be emulated by using two separate images and/or shapes alongside of MouseDown() / MouseUp() events attached to that specific control to swap the images out

@K.Dᴀᴠɪs, Thanks for info.  I hadn't realized that ActiveX was such an old system.  I suppose I could play around more with Shapes and Images and see if I could get them to behave the way I'd like.  Hadn't thought of using MouseDown() or MouseUp() events to trigger visual changes.  I guess that's a testament to my inexperience.

If you really want to dig into it, it's technically possible to create your own form controls outside of Excel. Visual Studio Community is a free IDE provided by MS that can create custom form controls. Since this is all COM/ActiveX based, you'll probably want to do this via .NET Framework. But some of the underlying issues is still present as the framework is also pretty old (I think updates stopped around Win XP era), but it could offer more flexibility. It's going to be highly technical, but would be the closest you can get to full customization of your controls.

@K.Dᴀᴠɪs I'll keep that in mind.  I think for what I'm currently working on, the available tools should be enough to get it working.  But if I'm feeling like going for a deep dive, I'll look further into that.  Thanks!
